# Tkinter window operations

Tags: python, tkinter

For starters, I'm working on someone elses code.

In this code it opens an initial tkinter window, the user enters some info and presses a button.  Then another tkinter window opens asking for username and password.  User supplies creds and presses the ok button.

It all works great except the child window, username password window, does not close.

I've been hacking on it for a couple hours and frustration has been my only fruit.

I've been able to close the child window with destroy but that kills the whole app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a *short* standalone code snippet that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: Ok below is a link to the original script.  From what I've gathered, the primary window is on line 3022 and the window I can't get to close is on line 2044, the authors comment is on line 2154

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WHLSvE68

Answer (score 1):

If the child window is a `tk.Toplevel`, then it can be closed by having the `ok` button call the `destroy` method:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        window = tk.Toplevel(master)
        close_button = tk.Button(
            window, text='OK/Close', command=window.destroy)
        close_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)


class MainApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        close_button = tk.Button(master, text='Child window',
                                 command=Child)
        close_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)

root = tk.Tk()
app = MainApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when exactly you want to close the window, but if that window is not required at all, you can use `Window_name.withdraw()`